# How to add/remove movie clip using other .as file beside the main?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop, movieclip

as the title says.

I have a practice.fla and on that have an Main.as file on it, I also have a movie clip that have an AS Linkage PlayButton on the library. I know how to display/remove it using the Main.as, now I have another .as file. Using the same technique done in Main.as, it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do it?

Sorry if it is already been asked. I've tried searching the web but I can't pinpoint the exact.

Comment: It is completely unclear (to me) what do you want to do. Can you please provide your code that does not work?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and not being clear enough. But even I having a hard time comprehending it. I don't really have a solid code. I'll try to put screenshot. 

https://www.flickr.com/photos/67116898@N08/16560137815/

I have an MenuGraphics.as and I want to use that to display movie clips that is on the Library.

Comment: in practice.fla you should have `import MenuGraphics;` then you can do something like `var mg:MenuGraphics = new MenuGraphics(); addChild(mg); mg.addChild(new PlayButton());` but it is still not clear because you should show what code is in fla, in Main.as and in MenuGraphics.as.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add movieclips as long as the class is derived from a **Sprite** or a **MovieClip** itself. Though keep in mind that you must add this new class to the stage for any children to be visible.

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {
    public var other:Other;

    public function Main() {
        this.addChild(other = new Other);
    }
}

public class Other extends Sprite {
    public function Other() {
        this.addChild(new Sprite());
    }
}
```